The problem with line wrapping without spaces in a table cell when converting using the plugin org.dita.pdf2
To convert from a dita format to a pdf file, I use dita-ot v.3.7.4 together with the org.dita.pdf2 plugin. Faced with the problem of the text going beyond the table cell if this text does not contain spaces.
as you can see in the second field, the text has gone outside the cell

If this is a xslt question please show us what you tried to solve the issue.

You can

Shorten the string
Reduce the font size
Enlarge the cell
Tokenize the string and add a zero width space character (invisible) after each „_“ character.


As an example for what Stefan answered, the XSLT template which adds a zero width space after each "_", allowing the PDF processor to break the line, would look like:
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '_', '_&#8203;')"/>
</xsl:template>


Many thanks to Radu and Stefan. I have slightly corrected the code, since I am only interested in transferring text in a table cell, and also added character variants after which it is possible to transfer.
Here is my version of the code:
<xsl:template match="entry//text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '[\\.,\\-\\+\\/\\*;:)aeiouAEIOUаеёиоуыэюяАЕЁИОУЫЭЮЯьЬъЪ]', '$0&#8203;')"/>
</xsl:template>

